# $http request is passed to the server in angular js without specify it on the client side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I saw a demo of an authentication using angular js and JWS auth02 metodología and I refocterd it a little...
I am using express (node js) on the server side to define myApp.

my question is this - on the client side I am doing this http GET call:

```
   $http({url: '/api/restricted', method: 'GET'})
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.message = $scope.message + ' ' + data.name;  
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      alert(data);
    });
```

on the server side I am getting the id from the http GET request:

```
app.get('/api/restricted', function (req, res) {
   res.json({
    name: req.user.id
  });
});
```

and it is working.. the only problem is that I don't see where I defined a GET request with a user entity... all I see is that the GET http request get a method and a url:

```
   $http({url: '/api/restricted', method: 'GET'})
```

so where is this magic     `name: req.user.id`

is coming from?

Thanks...

more of the code (may be relavent...):

index. html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Angular Authentication</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./auth.client.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-cookies.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="UserCtrl">
      <span ng-show="isAuthenticated">{{welcome}}</span>
      <form ng-show="!isAuthenticated" ng-submit="submit()">
        <input ng-model="user.username" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" />
        <input ng-model="user.password" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
      </form>
      <div>{{error}}</div>
      <div ng-show="isAuthenticated">
        <a ng-click="callRestricted()" href="">Shh, this is private!</a>
        <br>
        <div>{{message}}</div>
        <a ng-click="logout()" href="">Logout</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

client side

```
myApp.controller('UserCtrl', ["$scope", "$http","$window","$cookies", function ($scope, $http, $window,$cookies) {
  $scope.callRestricted = function () {
    $http({url: '/api/restricted', method: 'GET'})
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.message = $scope.message + ' ' + data.name;  
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      alert(data);
    });
  };

myApp.factory('authInterceptor',["$rootScope", "$q","$cookies", 
  function ($rootScope, $q,$cookies) {
    return {
      request: function (config) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        if ($cookies.get('token')) {
          config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookies.get('token');
        }
        return config;
      },
      responseError: function (rejection) {
        if (rejection.status === 401) {
        // handle the case where the user is not authenticated
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
}]);

myApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
});
```

and this code on the server side:

```
 var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); 
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt'); 

var secret = 'ssasDSA223Sasdas2sdsa23123dvxcgyew231';

var app = express();

// We are going to protect /api routes with JWT
app.use('/api', expressJwt({secret: secret}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  if (err.constructor.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
  }
});

app.post('/authenticate', function (req, res) {
  //TODO validate req.body.username and req.body.password
  //if is invalid, return 401
  if (!(req.body.username === 'john.doe' && req.body.password === 'foobar')) {
    res.status(401).send('Wrong user or password');
    return;
  }

  var profile = {
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Doe',
    email: 'John.Doe@gmail.com',
    id: 333333333
  };

  // We are sending the profile inside the token
  var token = jwt.sign(profile, secret, { expiresInMinutes: 60*5 });
  res.json({ token: token });
});

app.get('/api/restricted', function (req, res) {
   res.json({
    name: req.user.id
  });
});

app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('listening on http://127.0.0.1:8080');
});
```

Comment: It looks like in each request, via the `authInterceptor` you're sending the JWT auth token in the header which contains all the information necessary to derive the user's id.  Is that your question or am I confused?  Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are using the express-jwt library. Per the documentation, the express-jwt library is `Middleware that validates JsonWebTokens and sets req.user.`

This occurs when the middleware is invoked on this line: `app.use('/api', expressJwt({secret: secret}));`

Comment: You are right.. I'll read more on the documentation to fully understand the req.user magic

Comment: Awesome. Check out the index.js file in the github repo. The property name `user` is defined on line 31 and attached to the request on line 113 (it also appears that you can define the property name yourself in the `requestProperty` option). Hope this helps uncover the magic!

Answer (score 0):

Common way to set Authorization data "accessToken" in angular is on setting http headers like

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Token'] = token
```

find this in app.run method on angular app
And the server side recognize the user by the access token provided in the headers of he request